# Does urllib or urllib2 in Python 2.5 support https?

Tags: python, https, urllib2, urllib, python-2.5

Thanks for the help in advance. I am puzzled that the same code works for python 2.6 but not 2.5.  Here is the code

```
import cgi, urllib, urlparse, urllib2
url='https://graph.facebook.com'

req=urllib2.Request(url=url)
p=urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = cgi.parse_qs(p.read())
```

And here is the exception I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t2.py", line 6, in <module>
    p=urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/home/userx/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "/home/userx/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 381, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/userx/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 404, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/home/userx/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 360, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/userx/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 1140, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Again, appreciate for help.

Answer (score 8):

Most likely you're 2.5 version as been compiled without ssl support.

Try this :

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.ssl
<function ssl at 0xb7ce602c>
```

to check if ssl is present (ie, you don't catch an AttributeError)

Comment: I just noticed more recent python's always have this function defined, but it prints a deprication warning if you call it, a better check might be to `import _ssl`

Answer (score 6):

If you get

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

you have to install openssl, libssl-dev and rebuild python from sources

Comment: Or openssl-devel on CentOS/RedHat platforms.

Comment: @Oleg:  thanks for the install requirements.. they were very helpful in resolving this problem.