# urlopen error [Errno 110] with https and python 2.7 on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

I am on ubuntu 12.10 with python 2.7 installed.  I wrote a simple script based on other posts to test http and https connections:

```
import urllib2, urllib

def set_proxy():
  proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://<proxyhost>:<proxyport>'})
  opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
  urllib2.install_opener(opener)

def http_call():
  conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.whatismyip.com/')
  return conn.read()

def https_call():
  conn = urllib2.urlopen('https://chase.com/')
  return conn.read()

set_proxy()
webpage = open('webpage.html', 'w')
return_str = https_call()
webpage.write(return_str)
webpage.close()
print ("check for output in webpage.html")
```

The test with http works fine, but with https produces the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
  return_str = https_call()
File "test.py", line 13, in https_call
  conn = urllib2.urlopen('https://chase.com/')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 401, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 419, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1219, in https_open
  return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

Here is my setup:

```
root@sc11137376:/usr/local/pythonbrew#  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:        12.10
Codename:       quantal

root@sc11137376:/usr/local/pythonbrew# python --version
Python 2.7.3

root@sc11137376:/usr/local/pythonbrew# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

I saw in [a similar, older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875402/does-urllib-or-urllib2-in-python-2-5-support-https) suggestions to rebuild python from source with openssl installed.  I am hoping there is a different solution to my problem, since this is much newer ubuntu/python version and openssl is already on the system.

Any pointers appreciated.

**Note:** Setting HTTPS_PROXY in the environment changed the error message to the following (from error number 110 to 113):

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>
```

Btw, the following also fails:

```
root@sc11137376:/usr/local/pythonbrew# openssl s_client -connect encrypted.google.com:443
connect: No route to host
connect:errno=113
```

Not sure if there is anything I can do to resolve this problem.

Comment: I have got the same problem with https after several hours in production. Ubuntu 12.04 python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

**URLError:urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host**

I had a same kind of error : i wanted to execute some scripts remotely on machine B from machine A (which does some browser automation stuff) and finally i had the error as stated above later i disabled the firewall setting for the HTTPS.

How i disabled the fire wall setting on RHEL6.4 ?
- click settings (on left side of the panel) > Administration > Firewall > on "Firewall Configuration" window : check the "secure WWW (HTTPS)" -(you need to be root user) >> click "Apply" >> click the disable button.

later i was able to execute the scripts on remote machine B without any hassle.